# C Code to check whether a number is a product of primes or not does not work for large numbers

Tags: c

I developed this C Code Below that executes two functions. The first one, `modozero`, finds the next prime number, and I think it's working properly.
However, the function `modoum`, which is supposed to find if a number is the product of two prime numbers is not working for large numbers and I don't really know how to work on that.
I think the problem has got to do with Time of Execution, but I'm not sure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long int modozero(long int num);
long int primeverification(long int num);
long int modoum(long int num);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long int modo, num;

    modo = atoi(argv[1]);
    num = atoi(argv[2]);

    if (!modo)
        modozero(num);
    else
        modoum(num);

    return 0;
}

long int primeverification(long int num) {
    long int i, remainder;
    for (i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++) {
        remainder = num % i;
        if (!remainder)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

long int modozero(long int num) {
    long int isprime = 0;
    while (!isprime) {
        num++;

        isprime = primeverification(num);
        printf("is prime %ld \n", isprime);
    }
    printf("%ld \n", num);
    return num;
}

long int modoum(long int num) {
    long int i, j, remainder;

    for (i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++) {
        if (primeverification(i)) {
            remainder = num % i;

            if (!remainder) {
                j = num / i;
                if (primeverification(j)) {
                    printf("%ld %ld", i, j);
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Examples of executions:

```
$ ./prime 1 6
2 3

$ ./prime 1 1000
#No print since 1000 is not a product of primes

$ ./prime 1 908118221
30133 30137

$ ./prime 1 908118220
#When I do this imput, the program doesn't finish the execution
#Weird that it doesn't work for this number that we know that is not a product of primes and it is smaller than the previous number we tested
```

Comment: I think the program is verifying that 454059110 is not a prime number, by doing 227029555 divisions. It should only take maybe half a second, not forever.

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: The `atoi()` function returns an `int` and won't handle bigger values correctly.  Use `strtol()` but be careful with the error detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason your program does not work with large numbers is you use `atoi` to convert the command line arguments to numbers, and this function has undefined behavior for representations of number beyond the range of type `int`. You should use `strtol()`:

```
modo = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);
num = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0);
```

And you should check for conversion errors.

Here is a modified version of the `main` function:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long int modo, num;
    char *p;

    errno = 0;
    modo = strtol(argv[1], &p, 0);
    if (p == argv[1] || *p != '\0' || errno != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "conversion error: %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    errno = 0;
    num = strtol(argv[2], &p, 0);
    if (p == argv[2] || *p != '\0' || errno != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "conversion error: %s\n", argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (modo == 0)
        modozero(num);
    else
        modoum(num);

    return 0;
}
```

Furthermore, the function `primeverification` is too slow for large numbers: if the number is prime, it will iterate `num / 2` times, which may take a long time. You should stop at the square root of `num`, which can be tested this way:

```
long int primeverification(long int num) {
    long int i, remainder;

    if (num <= 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        /* the only even prime number is 2 */
        return num == 2;
    }
    /* only test odd divisors from here */
    for (i = 3; i <= num / i; i += 2) {
        remainder = num % i;
        if (!remainder)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

You should also remove the `printf("is prime %ld \n", isprime);` in function `modozero`.

In function `modoum`, it would be more efficient to test `i` for primeness only if `i` divides `num` evenly, and stopping at the square root of `num` is also recommended (because one of the prime factors must be `<= num`):

```
long int modoum(long int num) {
    long int i, j, remainder;

    /* test 2, then 3, 5, 7, etc. */
    for (i = 2; i <= num / i; i += 1 + (i & 1)) {
        remainder = num % i;
        if (!remainder && primeverification(i)) {
            j = num / i;
            if (primeverification(j)) {
                printf("%ld = %ld * %ld\n", num, i, j);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a modified version of the full program:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long int primeverification(long int num) {
    long int i, remainder;

    if (num <= 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        /* the only even prime number is 2 */
        return num == 2;
    }
    /* only test odd divisors from here */
    for (i = 3; i <= num / i; i += 2) {
        remainder = num % i;
        if (!remainder)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

// output and return the next prime
long int modozero(long int start) {
    long int num = start;
    while (num < LONG_MAX) {
        num++;
        if (primeverification(num)) {
            printf("%ld\n", num);
            return num;
        }
    }
    printf("no primes larger than %ld\n", start);
    return -1;
}

long int modoum(long int num) {
    long int i, j, remainder;

    /* test 2, then 3, 5, 7, etc. */
    for (i = 2; i <= num / i; i += 1 + (i & 1)) {
        remainder = num % i;
        if (!remainder && primeverification(i)) {
            j = num / i;
            if (primeverification(j)) {
                printf("%ld = %ld * %ld\n", num, i, j);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

long int convert(const char *s) {
    char *p;
    long int num;

    errno = 0;
    num = strtol(s, &p, 0);
    if (p == s || *p != '\0' || errno != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "conversion error: %s\n", s);
        exit(1);
    }
    return num;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long int modo, num;

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "missing arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }
    modo = convert(argv[1]);
    num = convert(argv[2]);

    if (modo == 0)
        modozero(num);
    else
        modoum(num);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `i * i <= num` expression could fail due to arithmetic overflow. A safer alternative is `i <= num / i`. Hopefully, a smart compiler would notice the `num % i` afterwards and optimize the division and remainder calculations into a single operation.

Comment: @IanAbbott: yes of course, my bad. Answer amended.

Comment: There is of course `ldiv()` which exists to exploit that remainder is a by-product of division on almost (or actually) all hardware. But it's a bit dated because in my experience commercial compilers spot the a/b combo a%b and do it for you when optimisation is on. I know gcc and visual studio do.

Comment: What does this notation make?
i += 1 + (i & 1)

Comment: @GWA: `i += 1 + (i & 1)` increments `i` by `1` if `i` is even and `2` if `i` is odd, hence starting at `i = 2`, the next value will be `3`, then `5`, `7`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and comment, I learned a lot